# Point Azure VM to Local DNS

Tags: azure, dns

I feel like I may be trying to sprint before I can even walk here, but I'm getting there! I've got a VM on Azure that I want to be able to access a local fileserver from. We have the following setup:
$COMPANY.net is the local domain, $COMPANY.com is the Azure domain. They are connected using Azure AD Connect, and the VM on Azure is using AADDS; we have a site to site vpn setup between Azure and our local network. I can put in the IP address of the local fileserver and reach it from the Azure VM, but I can't resolve the name if I try that. I believe it is a DNS problem, I need the Azure VM to use my local DNS server to resolve the host name rather than the AADDS addresses. Do I need to set up a DNS server on Azure that will point the requests to my local DNS, or is there another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify DNS server for your Azure VM to use. The doc is quite large: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances.md

Your name resolution needs might go beyond the features provided by Azure. For example, you might need to use Microsoft Windows Server Active Directory domains, resolve DNS names between virtual networks. To cover these scenarios, Azure provides the ability for you to use your own DNS servers.

Comment: Hah, it's right in there! "Resolution of on-premises computer and service names from VMs or role instances in Azure." which is exactly what I need. Thank you!